# Django - best way to set up models for timeclock app?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on an employee timeclock app in Django mostly as a test project. I am a newbie and I am not sure how best to set up the models, etc.

I could create clockin and clockout models and reference the user as a foreign key. However then I am not sure the best way to calculate time between multiple clock-in and clock-out events in one day.

Any ideas about the best way to handle this most efficiently?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model structure depends on what functional do you want to add to your app.
It can be different models for check-in and check-out as you mentioned, it can be solo model like this:

```
class WorkVisit(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeginKey(User, ....)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

if you want to calculate difference you can do just:

```
difference = worker.check_in - worker.check_out
```

you can make it model property:

```
class WorkVisit(models.Model):
    worker = models.ForeginKey(User, ....)
    check_in = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    check_out = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def visit_duration(self):
        if not self.check_in or not self.check_out:
            return None
        return self.check_out - self.check_in
```

Comment: Vlad, how would I go about selecting the correct object to update when the check_out time was recorded?

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, you can find visits that are not *closed* by filtering something like:
user.visits.objects.filter(check_out=None)

Comment: I like this answer, nice work @VladMarchenko!